# Struggling with normal map

Tags: uv, normals

So I am working on a character to be taken into unity and frankly my normal map and Ambient occlusion are horrific...I'm wondering if it comes down to a bad original structure or something...I've attached some images to reference what issues I am running into..Thank you for any and all advice. 
[image: My original model]

[image: Problematic Normal Map]

[image: problematic Ambient Occlusion Map]

[image: UV map]

Comment: What issues specifically are you experiencing? Could you clarify what your question is?

Comment: I mean I'm unsure how to really explain. the texture given by the maps doesn't even come close to resembling my high poly texture when it is applied. It has a bunch of weird melted looking blobs in the texture. its all just very sloppy and just not even close.

Comment: "*I mean I'm unsure how to really explain*" Well you should really figure it out if you want any answers, because our guessing powers are really weak. Please edit your question and provide all the relevant details

Comment: figure it out myself so thanks for nothing. People who are new and looking for help don't need attitude by the way. I came here as a last resort but obviously that was a mistake. Don't be a troll, its just rude.

Comment: We all volunteer our time to try and help people out. We can't help people quickly  and efficiently if the problem isn't clear and well described, so you will get no answers. There are other questions that need answering as well. Don't blame @DuarteFarrajotaRamos for your bad question please. Take some responsibility.
Anyways, glad you have figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your models are not intersecting.  Your low poly model should be slightly larger than your high poly model and no part of the high poly model can protrude through any part of your low poly model.  Your model is kind of complex to do all at once.  You may trying breaking it down into smaller pieces (selecting parts in Edit mode and hitting P: By Selection) and baking them all to the same map individually(Uncheck CLEAR in the Bake Panel), then when all parts are baked, rejoin them by selecting all and hitting Ctrl J.

Comment: It also appears your margin may be too high and its overlapping your normals on top of themselves.  Change your margin in the bake panel to 1 or 2 px.